# compare specific values from objects with different keys Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

This is a silly question, but nothing I try works.
I have two objects `nft` and `web3.givenProvider`. Both contain an `address` as `"0x0000000000000"`, but they are under separate keys. `nft` is under `.seller` and `web3` is under `.selectedAddress`. Whenever I try to compare them using `_.isEqual or toString` it returns false even though the values are correct. I am not sure what I am missing here. I have even tried converting to an array and trying to `_.find` the address in the array, but that returned false.

```js
// removed question mark
console.log(nft.seller === web3.givenProvider.selectedAddress))
```

NFT `console.log()`
[image: NFT console.log]

Web3 `console.log()`
[image: Web3 console.log]

Comment: can you provide the actual objects excluding other non-related keys?

Comment: @OctaviaSima I added screenshots of both objects. The keys are `seller` and `selectedAddress` on the respective objects.

Comment: they dont equate to each other because NFT has upper case letters while Web3  have lowercase on all letters. If both values should be case insensitive, convert both to the same case (lower/upper) then compare them. e.g. `console.log(nft.seller.toLowerCase() === web3.givenProvider.selectedAddress.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: That was the issue! The API im using is changing the casing on the address for some reason.

Comment: Ill let you post the answer :)

Comment: Just posted the comment as an answer. Thanks @AS10

Comment: No thank you! That was such a silly issue on my part, I spent so much time and was very confused. I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They dont equate to each other because NFT has upper case letters while Web3 has all its letters on lowercase. If both values should be case insensitive, convert both to the same case (lower/upper) then compare them.

#### Sample:

```
console.log(nft.seller.toLowerCase() === web3.givenProvider.selectedAddress.toLowerCase())
```